# Showing video player on Node JS simple route

Tags: node.js, express

I have very simple node js application using express.
I have written route as below.

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json("Application is up and running on port 4003!");
});
```

It was running quite well, was showing "Application is up and running on port 4003!" as expected but now, it suddenly showing up window as below and same for all other routes too.

I have not added video tag anywhere in my application.

What I did wrong?

[image]

Similarly I tried to run in postman and showing as below
[image]

Here is response header

[image]

Comment: can you show the response headers?

Comment: I have added response header in my question, please check

Comment: as i can see request ends with 304 status code and not 200 maybe try different browser or incognito so request is not cached.

Comment: I tried in different browser , with incognito mode. Still same it is returning 304 status code.